# Remove the 'w' character under a figure

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In Draw.io I have a figure that has a small 'w' character centered underneath it.  The 'w' moves along with the figure.

How can I remove it?

[image: equation with blue dashed selection box; centered underneath is a small 'w']

Answer (score -1):

If you double-click a shape and click **Delete**, the letter should be removed. You probably used `position: Bottom` in the **Text** tab on the right. If this doesn't help, attach the file here (if possible) and tell me the Draw.io version you are using.

Comment: Hello @Marija I have a figure, not a shape. the link to the file is here (I'm using draw.io online) https://drive.google.com/file/d/134acqwNDo8UOXXuJlIKvqN4J7dRRftmy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you allow editing, please? At the moment, it is read-only so I am not able to test. Thanks,